# CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND. X11_XTest_LIB (ADVANCED)

Tags: makefile, cmake, debian

I'm trying to configure and compile virtualgl on Debian 10. Debian 10 has been installed as guest os,virtualized with vm-bhyve on FreeBSD 13. This because I want to use virtualGL + TurboVNC on Debian and I want to access the desktop manager xfce4 installed on Debian from FreeBSD. I've executed the following commands as root,but unfortunately I've encountered an error that stopped the configuration. Someone of you know how to fix it ? thanks.

```
#git clone https://github.com/VirtualGL/virtualgl.git

#cd virtualgl

#mkdir build

#cd build

#dpkg --add-architecture i386

#apt-get install g++-multilib libxv-dev:i386 libxtst-dev:i386 libx11-xcb-dev:i386 libxcb-keysyms1-dev:i386 libegl1-mesa-dev:i386 libglu1-mesa-dev:i386

#cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DTJPEG_LIBRARY="-L/usr/lib/ -lturbojpeg" ..

-- VirtualGL server components enabled (VGL_BUILDSERVER = 1)

-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Release

-- VERSION = 2.6.91, BUILD = 20210731

-- 64-bit build (x86_64)

-- CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = /opt/VirtualGL

-- CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR = bin (/opt/VirtualGL/bin)

-- CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR =  (/opt/VirtualGL)

-- CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR = doc (/opt/VirtualGL/doc)

-- CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR = include (/opt/VirtualGL/include)

-- CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR = lib64 (/opt/VirtualGL/lib64)

-- Linking with static libstdc++:
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.a

-- INLINE = __inline__ __attribute__((always_inline)) (VGL_FORCEINLINE = 1)

-- SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) encryption disabled (VGL_USESSL = 0)

-- X Video support disabled (VGL_USEXV = 0)

-- TJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR = /opt/libjpeg-turbo/include

-- TJPEG_LIBRARY = -L/usr/lib/ -lturbojpeg

-- Compiler flags =  -O3 -DNDEBUG

-- Linker flags =  -L/root/Scrivania/tmp/virtualgl/build/staticlib 
-static-libgcc 

-- Using /dev/urandom for random number generation

-- Using in-tree version of FLTK

-- XCB interposer enabled (VGL_FAKEXCB = 1)

-- OpenCL interposer enabled (VGL_FAKEOPENCL = 1)

-- EGL back end enabled (VGL_EGLBACKEND = 1)

-- RPM architecture = x86_64, DEB architecture = amd64
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
X11_XTest_LIB (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "tcbench" in directory /root/Scrivania/tmp/virtualgl/diags

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/Scrivania/tmp/virtualgl/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
GitHub - VirtualGL/virtualgl: Main VirtualGL repository
```

Comment: Do you have libxtst-dev installed?

Comment: It appears that you have installed 32-bit libraries (in particular, `libxtst-dev:i386`), but you are performing a 64-bit build.  64-bit programs require 64-bit libraries.